# Roblox Studio how to make that when the part size reached a specyific number it will do something

Tags: roblox

```
local code = game.Workspace.Script
local basep = game.Workspace.Baseplate
local sp = true


while sp == true do
    basep.Size = Vector3.new(basep.Size.X - 2,basep.Size.Y,basep.Size.Z - 2)
    wait(0.5)
    print(basep.Size)
end

if basep.Size == Vector3.new(10, 5, 10) then
    print("worked")
end
```

the last part isn't working, i don't know how to put that when it reaches the size X-10 Y-5 Y-10 then it stops (i put print("worked") so I can see if it is working)

Answer (score 0):

you would put the if block inside your endless loop, like so:

```
while sp == true do
    basep.Size = Vector3.new(basep.Size.X - 2,basep.Size.Y,basep.Size.Z - 2)
    print(basep.Size)

    if basep.Size == Vector3.new(10, 5, 10) then
        print("worked")
        break --     <=== add this if you want to break out of the loop
    end

    wait(0.5)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a [Tween](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Tween) to handle the animation, then attach a callback for when the animation ends.

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

-- choose an Instance to change
local basep = game.Workspace.Baseplate

-- create a list of properties to change during the animation
local goal = {
    Size = Vector3.new(10, 5, 10)
}

-- configure how the animation will work
local timeToComplete = 5 --seconds
local timeToDelay = 0 -- seconds
local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(timeToComplete, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.In, 0, false, timeToDelay)

-- create the animation and attach a listener for when the animation finishes
local tween = TweenService:Create(basep, tweenInfo, goal)
tween.Completed:Connect(function()
    print("worked")
end)
tween:Play()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.